# Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to send the consumer data

Tags: woocommerce

I am integrating Woo-commerce API’s in my wordpress site using Woo-commerce official rest sdk. I made a link using authentication endpoint URL. When I click the link it takes the user to Woo-commerce authentication page, where user login and Approve the request.

After approving the request it should take me to return url which i mention in the link. Instead it shows me the following error.

Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to send the consumer data.

Comment: Please share your request code and response data as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late for the answer but writing it for the people who will face the same issue in the future.

I was having the same issue and my problem was that the **callback_url** was wrong which was creating the error internally. So if you are getting this error, most probably your callback_url is not correct, please check that properly.

Comment: Yes, most of the issues are related to the callback_url which I found out the hard way should not contain port value or localhost (e.g : http://localhost:2398/callback). Simple way to mock this is by using Postman Mockservice, where a DNS is generated by Postman something similar to -> https://60113d769b74.ngrok.io , this URL was generated by using a tool called ngrok. Once that is done the WooCommerce Auth endpoint posts the key data to the callback_url. But now I'm getting
Error: An error occurred in the request and at the time were unable to send the consumer data.

Answer (score 1):

For whoever Shattique's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59613742/9155456)
did not work,
check the response status code sent by the `callback_url` handler.
Anything other than `200` will throw the error in OP's question.

Here is link to woocommerce [github repo](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/class-wc-auth.php#L279),
where it throws the error.

**TLDR:** Make sure `callback_url` handler returns `statusCode: 200`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as well, and in my case, the return_url on my backend server was accepting `GET` requests, I changed it to `POST`, and everything worked perfectly. I hope it helps!